# PhpStorm - downloading from remote server - items excluded - details

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm 2017.3

When right clicking on the project folder - in the **Remote Host** window - and selecting **"Download from here**" - the files then download from the server and overwrite your local project files in \PhpstormProjects.

Sometimes - in PhpStorm's "**File Transfer**" window - it will say "**4 items excluded**" or some other number.

Yet it does not give any further details about those items not downloaded.

**Is there a setting to see full details of "items excluded"?**

**Or a log file somewhere that will provide more details?**

Comment: Try to check for anything related in an idea.log file (Help > Show log in ...)

Comment: Thanks for that. Still doesn't say anything there about the "items excluded". I see definitions like "... 23 more". Seems strange to note that files were "excluded" without saying which files were "excluded". Seems like it could be the sort of thing you would want to know about.

Comment: Did you actually add any files/patterns to exclude?

Comment: Yes. I have some folder excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Moving from comments, posting this as answer.*

That's an expected behavior. In case of huge exclusions your upload log would get garbage'd. You can:

1) add "deployment" logging ([article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115)) - this would show excluded items in idea.log file (*Help > Show log ...*)

2) submit a feature request [at JetBrains tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI#newissue=yes) to implement an option to show excluded items